# How to add a default sorting order in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, sorting

In the folder sub folders I want to add "sort by date created" in the sort by menu.

I went into more and selected sort by date created to show in the sorting menu.

But its only doing it on the current folder and every time I add a new folder into a sub folder I have to go to more and select sort by date created from the options to show in the sorting menu.

I searched google and couldn't find anything useful to do it.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a folder that you have configured the way you want, in Windows Explorer,
go to the menu bar and go to “Tools” → “Folder options…”. 
This will bring up the “Folder Options” window. 
Go to the “View” tab and click on “Apply to Folders”:

[image: Folder Options]

If you have turned off (hidden) your menu bar,
and your Explorer window looks like this:

[image: Windows Explorer without menu bar]

then either

- Go to “Organize” → “Layout” and click on “Menu bar”. 
  This will enable (unhide) the menu bar. 
  Then follow the above instructions.
- Go to “Organize” → “Folder and search options”. 
  This will open the “Folder Options” window. 
  Then follow the above instructions.